# rotation of the camera Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to rotate the camera in a circle around the center of the object and so that the point that we are looking at the camera is on this circle on the opposite side (picture 1). When the camera rotates around the object, the view starts to turn over (picture 2). How to solve this problem?
That is my realisation of rotation around object. 
(maybe that is the problem of my project, but the **X** axis is directed to the left, the **Y** axis is up, the **Z** axis is forward)

```
camera.position.set((float) (x - 17 * Math.sin(angle)), 12, (float) (z - 17 * Math.cos(angle)));
    camera.lookAt((float) (x + 15 * Math.sin(angle)), 0, (float) (z + 15 * Math.cos(angle)));
```

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7p8R.jpg] [1]

[2]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiXer.png] [2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the camera up value.

```
camera.up.set(0, 1, 0); //sets rotation back to default

camera.position.set((float) (x - 17 * Math.sin(angle)), 12, (float) (z - 17 * Math.cos(angle)));
camera.lookAt((float) (x + 15 * Math.sin(angle)), 0, (float) (z + 15 * Math.cos(angle)));
camera.update();
```

Hope that helps.